# CSV Line Breaks

Tags: c#, .net, csv, newline

I'm building a csv file from database values. When I open the csv in excel everything is on one row. To counter this I've added either `\n` or `\r` after each row. Now when I open in excel starting at the second row there is an empty value throughout the rest of the first column.

IE:

```
value 1, value 2, value 3
       , value 1, value 2, value 3
       , value 1, value 2, value 3
       , value 1, value 2, value 3
```

I can add a newline or return before the first value, but then there is an empty row and column. How can I get this lined up?

My code:

```
try
{
    connection = new iDB2Connection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    command = new iDB2Command(commandString, connection);

    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);

    List<string> CsvList = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
        {
            CsvList.Add(item.ToString());
        }
        if (i == 1)
        {
            CsvList.Add(" ");
            CsvList.Add("Customer Service");
            CsvList.Add("Customer Service Representative" + "\r"); 
            // \r and \n not working
        }
    }

    System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter;
    streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, true);

    string CsvString = string.Join(",", CsvList.ToArray());
    streamWriter.WriteLine(CsvString);
    streamWriter.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("File saved as " + fileName);

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Make your life easier and use `String.Join` and `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: @gunr2171 He is using `Join`, just not correctly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll be a heck of a lot easier if you just build up a list of *lines*, rather than a flattened list of single values.  Since you've flattened your list already when you use `Join` you're putting commas after newlines values, for example.

Instead join together the values for each line, and then just keep track of the entire lines:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    CsvList.Add(string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
}
```

Now that you have a list of lines, we can just use `File.AppendAllLines` to simply and easily write out all of the lines to the end of the file:

```
File.AppendAllLines(fileName, CsvList);
```

Or, if you would like to stream the results to the file rather than copying all of the data over to a list and holding it all in memory at once, you can do this:

```
var lines = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => string.Join(",", row.ItemArray));
File.AppendAllLines(fileName, lines);
```

Comment: Nice shortcut joining `ItemArray`

Comment: @ChrisMantle Well, it's code that I've written more than a fair few times myself.

Comment: Just have to figure out how to add some hard coded values. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DouglasBubbletrousers You can `Concat` some values to the `ItemArray` by just adding `.Concat(new[]{"a", "b"})`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an array and handling adding new-lines yourself, use a `StringBuilder`, and commit each row one at a time:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    List<string> csvList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
    {
        csvList.Add(item.ToString());
    }

    if (i == 1)
    {
        csvList.Add(" ");
        csvList.Add("Customer Service");
        csvList.Add("Customer Service Representative");
    }

    sb.WriteLine(string.Join(",", csvList));
}

System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter;
streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, true);

streamWriter.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
streamWriter.Close();
Console.WriteLine("File saved as " + fileName);
```